# Can't make gwt json serialization work with overlay system - array always empty

Tags: json, gwt, overlay

I'm trying, for the first time, to parse json in gwt and it's not working. Since I'm a newbie this might be some obvious stupid mistake. The array is not retrieved correctly.

This is the piece of code on which I'm debugging:

```
String json = "{\"lokacije\":[{\"sifraLokacije\":1,\"nazivLokacije\":\"Policijska stanica\",\"brojDokumenata\":70}],\"status\":1}";
LocationsResponse locationsResponse = createLocationsResponse("("+json+")");
// this is ok, status is 1
int status = locationsResponse.getStatus();
// length of this array is 0 and you can see from json that it has one element (the same if it has more)
int brojLokacija = locationsResponse.getLokacije().length();
```

...

```
private final native LocationsResponse createLocationsResponse(String json) /*-{
    return eval(json);
}-*/;
```

LocationsResponse class:

```
public class LocationsResponse extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected LocationsResponse() {}

    public final native int getStatus() /*-{ return this.status; }-*/;

    public final native JsArray<JSOLokacija> getLokacije() /*-{ this.lokacije; }-*/;

}
```

JSOLokacija class:

```
public class JSOLokacija extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected JSOLokacija() {} ;

    public final native int getSifraLokacije() /*-{ this.sifraLokacije; }-*/;

    public final native String getNazivLokacije() /*-{ this.nazivLokacije; }-*/;

    public final native int getBrojDokumenata() /*-{ this.brojDokumenata; }-*/;

}
```

Comment: I was missing a return in JSNI method. Just ignore me. I feel like I've just seen Twighlight, throwing away 3 hours of my life...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second edit: Wow, I'm just useless today. My first answer returned JSONValue, which is pretty annoying if you want to work with a JSO.

Edit: Aaand just noticed your comment that you fixed it... Still, using the provided tools will tend to help prevent you from getting into annoying situations like this.

Here is another tool you should be aware of, esp if you are after using JSON, and not just objects from JS: AutoBeans (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) - with these, you don't need to write out the JSNI code, just define the properties you expect to have, and it will work out all the wrapper code.

---

First, mostly useless answer:

`eval` doesn't work like that - it is meant to run JS, not turn JSON into data, and a json expression (also a js expression) isn't a legal statement in Javascript. Adding the "(" and ")" around the content is why it is working at all, but this is somewhat risky - usually it is better to trust the browser to do it right if possible:

Use `JSONParser.parseStrict` (or `parseLenient` if you expect parsing errors, but are absolutely certain that no possible attacks could be coming from there - this will end up calling eval for you, but this way you dont have to maintain it) instead to make sure the content is safe, and to parse it to js correctly. To turn this into a JSO then, you call `.isObject().getJavaScriptObject()` on the result of the parse method, which you then have to .cast() to the right value.

Comment: I saw similar advices not to use eval(...) on several places and I'm a bit puzzled because I'm doing this from an example on GWT site, as far as I can understand they recommend this approach but a lot of people is saying that it's bad...

Comment: A lot of the examples are quite old. Eval itself is not bad, it is a natural (and necessary) part of the JavaScript language, but it comes with some risk. If there was a risk of reading a malformed xml file into an app and having code execute, I think people would like it a lot less than they do, and that is essentially what eval does - except it is intended to do this. JSONParser's strict parsing takes advantage of the browser's ability to verify the data before reading it, and if that fails, verifies it in code instead.

Comment: OK, so problem with eval is security risc basically? I'm consuming JSON from my own server in this app...

Comment: Risk management is the name of the game, yes - I use a JSON library on the server, and read it on my own client, so the risk is already very small, but if a bug were discovered in the JSON lib or the browser, or I made a mistake in how I pass it back and forth, I could put customers and their data at risk. Example: RequestFactory, with both client and server implementation built by GWT in Java, still uses the browser's JSON parsing if available, or falls back to a hand written parser rather than eval.

Comment: Just a small note: use JsonUtil class for parsing JSON to overlays. Will use native parsing if available.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasBroyer, I knew there was a better answer somewhere. Kind of annoying that the capitalization of Json is inconsistent, even within the GWT classes.